# When a Time Lord dies, are they eradicated from history?

Tags: doctor-who, time-travel

Time Lords exist within a non-linear perception of time. When one dies, do they just disappear from the universal timeline? If not, what stops the surviving Time Lords from interacting with deceased Time Lords?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment, all of the Time Lords have been taken outside the universal timeline because of the Time Lock.

However, prior to that nothing was stopping a Time Lord from interacting with a previous version of a deceased Time Lord, similar to how Rose was able to interact with her (dead) father by travelling back to his wedding day.  The caveat being that the interaction must be consistent with both timelines and not a change of history, i.e. you can't go back and save the Time Lord from dying.

It would lead to a similar situation to the Doctor and River or Jack, as both have the ability to travel back and forth through time by various means at various points.

Comment: River is actually a really good example because we all know what happens to her even though she doesn't!